# Finding the frequency that each column is a row minimum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
       A     B     C     D
 0   1.2     0   1.1   3.2
 1   2.3   2.2   2.2   2.5
 2   1.1   1.5     0   1.7
 3     0   1.1   1.4   1.2
 4   3.3   3.0   1.7   1.7
 5   1.1   1.0   2.2   2.5
 6   5.0   5.0   5.0   5.0
```

I would like to find the frequency that each column contains the row's minimum. So in some format:

```
B: 2               # rows 0, 5
A: 1               # row 3
C: 1               # row 2
(B, C): 1          # row 1
(C, D): 1          # row 4
(A, B, C, D): 1    # row 6
```

I am currently doing `df.min(axis=1)` and then looping through each row using `df.iloc`... but there has to be a better way.

In case it matters, I have a couple hundred columns, a couple thousand rows, and it represents a sample, so I have to perform the operation roughly a million times. I must be missing an obvious pandas or numpy method that will do this both pythonically and reasonably efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC,

1. Transpose the dataset (making it easier with axis)
2. Identify the location of min values in each column.
3. Identify the column names for each min
4. Value counts

```
df = df.T

result = (df.eq(df.min())
            .apply(lambda x:tuple(x.index[x]))
            .value_counts())
```

Comment: I used this solution, since although it is slower than @ShubhamSharma's solution, it is (to me) the most intuitive and doesn't require postprocessing of the column names.

Answer (score 4):

Use, [`DataFrame.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html), [`DataFrame.min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.min.html) to create a boolean mask then use [`DataFrame.dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) on `df.columns` and this mask then count the freq using [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
m = df.eq(df.min(axis=1), 0)
freq = m.dot(df.columns + ',').str.rstrip(',').value_counts()
```

---

```
# print(freq)
B          2
C,D        1
A          1
A,B,C,D    1
C          1
B,C        1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: That is almost the exact same solution I arrived at.  +1 `df.eq(df.min(axis=1), axis=0).dot(df.columns).value_counts()`

Comment: Thanks @ScottBoston ;).

Comment: Thanks! I suspected this would have a simple answer, hence am unsurprised that I very quickly got a variety of ways of going about it. On my actual data, your answer is the fastest posted (by almost a factor of two), but requires string manipulation to use the final answer. Could you remedy this please? (I know I specified "in some format", I should probably have been a little more precise)

Comment: You want the index  enclosed in brackets. Right?

Comment: I'd like an iterable, ideally. (I know that breaks my requested output -- for which I apologize -- is the etiquette here that I edit the requested output?)

Comment: Use, `freq.index = freq.reset_index()['index'].str.split(',').agg(tuple)`

Comment: Or you can use, `freq.index = [tuple(idx) for idx in freq.index.str.split(',')]`

Comment: Doable, but more string manipulation than ideal. I think in my actual use case, I will go with @MarkWang's answer, but yours is faster and answers the question as posed. Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

By using `stack` with `unstack`

```
df.eq(df.min(1),0).stack().loc[lambda x : x].reset_index(level=1).groupby(level=0)['level_1'].agg(tuple).value_counts()
(B,)            2
(C, D)          1
(A,)            1
(B, C)          1
(A, B, C, D)    1
(C,)            1
Name: level_1, dtype: int64
```